# C# Parsing Complex XML LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, parsing, serialization

I have been trying to parse the following XML file with some success.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Settings>
    <Tasks>
        <Task ID="1" Name="task_1" Active="1" NextEID="25" AR="0" CacheNames="random">
            <Schedules>
                <Schedule OnlyUntilFirstSuccess="0" FailIfNoSuccessInSched="0" RunEvenIfNotif="0">
                    <Days>
                        <DayOfWeek>Monday</DayOfWeek>
                        <DayOfWeek>Tuesday</DayOfWeek>
                        <DayOfWeek>Wednesday</DayOfWeek>
                        <DayOfWeek>Thursday</DayOfWeek>
                        <DayOfWeek>Friday</DayOfWeek>
                        <DayOfWeek>Saturday</DayOfWeek>
                        <DayOfWeek>Sunday</DayOfWeek>
                    </Days>
                    <Frequency>
                        <Interval StartTime="09:45" EndTime="09:45" EveryMinutes="0"></Interval>
                    </Frequency>
                </Schedule>
            </Schedules>
        </Task>
        <Task ID="2" Name="task_2" Active="1" NextEID="25" AR="0" CacheNames="random">
            <Schedules>
                <Schedule OnlyUntilFirstSuccess="0" FailIfNoSuccessInSched="0" RunEvenIfNotif="0">
                    <Days>
                        <DayOfWeek>Monday</DayOfWeek>
                        <DayOfWeek>Tuesday</DayOfWeek>
                        <DayOfWeek>Wednesday</DayOfWeek>
                        <DayOfWeek>Thursday</DayOfWeek>
                        <DayOfWeek>Friday</DayOfWeek>
                        <DayOfWeek>Saturday</DayOfWeek>
                        <DayOfWeek>Sunday</DayOfWeek>
                    </Days>
                    <Frequency>
                        <Interval StartTime="12:45" EndTime="09:45" EveryMinutes="0"></Interval>
                    </Frequency>
                </Schedule>
            </Schedules>
        </Task>
    </Tasks>
</Settings>
```

Using several tutorials online I have pieced together the following C# code :

```
public static void ParseXml()
        {
            string strFile = "File.xml";

            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(strFile);

            var tasks = from s in xdoc.Descendants("Tasks")
                        select new
                        {
                            taskID = s.Element("Task").Attribute("ID").Value,
                            taskName = s.Element("Task").Attribute("Name").Value,
                            taskActive = s.Element("Task").Attribute("Active").Value,
                            taskSchedule = s.Element("Task").Element("Schedules").Element("Schedule").Element("Days")
                        };

            foreach (var t in tasks)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task Id :: {0}", t.taskID);
                Console.WriteLine("Task Name :: {0}", t.taskName);
                Console.WriteLine("Task Status :: {0}", t.taskActive);
                Console.WriteLine("Task Schedule :: {0}", t.taskSchedule);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

My goals is to parse out each task, task ID, Name, Days, Frequency. I'd like to ultimately be able to use these values to chart the TaskID and StartTime on a scatter plot graph. I tried creating the following classes thinking it might help me deal with it the file but I don't know how to tie it all together.

```
        public class Task
        {
            public static int taskId { get; set; }
            public static string taskName { get; set; }
        }

        public class Schedule
        {
            public enum DayOfWeek
            {
                Monday,
                Tuesday,
                Wednsday,
                Thursday,
                Friday,
                Saturday,
                Sunday
            }
        }

        public class Frequency
        {
            public static DateTime startTime { get; set; }
            public static DateTime endTime { get; set; }
            public static int everyMins { get; set; }
        }
```

Any help / direction would be appreciated. Please just don't post the solution if you have one. Please explain it so that I can learn from it and contribute to this community in the future.

Thanks!
Gabe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you'll need to structure your classes as per the source XML. So a `Settings` class within which you have `Tasks` and so on. Something like this. I haven't put in all the XML attributes of course. But you should get the gist. You need the `[XMLAttribute]` attribute decorating your properties representing XML attributes. Also all the property names are case sensitive. So be sure they match (ID instead of Id). There are ways around this using attributes though:

```
    public class Settings
    {
        public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    }

    public class Task
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Schedule> Schedules { get; set; }

    }

    public class Schedule
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string OnlyUntilFirstSuccess { get; set; }
        public List<DayOfWeek> Days { get; set; }
        public Frequency Frequency { get; set; }

    }
    public class Frequency
    {
        public Interval Interval { get; set; }
    }

    public class Interval
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string StartTime { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string EndTime { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public int EveryMins { get; set; }
    }
```

Then you can use an `XmlSerializer` to serialize the XML to your class. So your `ParseXml()` method should look something like this:

```
    public static void ParseXml()
    {
        string fileName = "File.xml";
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xdoc.ToString()))
        {
            try
            {
                var settings = (Settings)new XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings)).Deserialize(reader);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle exceptions as you see fit
            }
        }
    }
```

Other things to note: don't name variable strxxxxx to denote they are strings and standard convention is that public variable names start with capital letters. 
Also, you'll need the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
```

Comment: So, if my XML file contains other elements \ attributes I need to create a class for each even if I don't care about them for my overall project?

Comment: @ Ashwin Nair - Also what is the convention for private variables ? are those to be in lowercase? And I've often seen variables with a underscore "_" which preceeds the name. What does the underscore denote?

Comment: @ Ashwin Nair - a few more questions, I am not sure I understand the way you declared the Frequency and Interval classes.  Could you elaborate a bit on this? Also I've seen code where the decorator on the property not only designates the object type but also the property name like : [XMLAttribute("EveryMinutes")] is this unnecessary? if so why?

Comment: wow..that's a lot of questions...okay..1. You need to add classes / properties only for those elements / attributes that you're interested in. Note that I've left out quite a few of the properties. Similarly, if, for example, you'd not created a class called Frequency and didn't have the property, it would still work fine; only you wouldn't, obviously, have the data.2. You can stick to whatever conventions you're okay with. What I mentioned was a generally accepted standard for C# is all. Private vars are usually [camel- cased](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Also, I added a Frequency and Interval classes assuming you'd wanted the  corresponding information from the XML you provided. You don't need to use it if you don't need it. About the `[XMLAttribute("EveryMinutes")]` style you mentioned, it's used if your property name is different to the corresponding element / attribute in your XML, so your XML serializer knows that the incoming XML attribute / element is to be populated into the property with that particular name.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for answering my questions!